# retrieve all values of fleet_service_type.name into sale.order

Tags: python-2.7, openerp-7

The FLEET module has a list of service types

```
class fleet_service_type(osv.Model):
    _name = 'fleet.service.type'
    _description = 'Type of services available on a vehicle'
    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Name', required=True, translate=True),
        'cost':fields.float('Cost Of Service',required=True),
        'category': fields.selection([('contract', 'Contract'), ('service', 'Service'), ('both', 'Both')], 'Category', required=True, help='Choose wheter the service refer to contracts, vehicle services or both'),
    }
fleet_service_type()
```

i want to have a field in my sale.order module that will be the dropdownlist of all 'name' values in the fleet module.
Can anyone suggest how to i do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For get all value of relationship object (Fleet Service Type), you need to add `many2one relationship` on `Sale Order` with target object.

Put this code in your `.py` file

```
class sale_order(osv.Model):       
    _inherit = 'sale.order'
    _columns = {
        'fleet_id': fields.many2one('fleet.service.type', 'Fleet Service Type'),
    }
```

And do some customization on `view xml file`.

```
<record id="view_sale_order_extended_form1" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">sale.order.form1.extend</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="partner_id" position="before">
                <field name="fleet_id"/>
            </field>
        </field>
    </record>
```

After this you can see field `Fleet Service Type` after `Customer` field in `Sale Order Form.` And you can select your desire value of `Fleet Service Type`.

Hope this will help you.